# Limit rewrite rule to exclude a certain directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url

When a a rewrite rule to allow us to make friendly URL's with an ID number. The story is only pulled through the ID number, so the text at the end doesn't really matter.

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$    /news/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/.*$ /news/story.php?id=$1
```

Our problem comes when any file linked within /news/images/ , it gets redirected as well. So anything that displays an image from /news/images/ doesn't work.

Can someone help me out? How can we limit the rewrite so that it says "If it's in the /images/ subdirectory, don't rewrite the path"?

Comment: Actually, basically we want the rewrite rule to say "if it's inside ANY directory below /news/ do not rewrite the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the simple route and just avoid the rewrite if the file exists:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$    /news/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Ignore the RewriteRule if the request points to a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !=tags [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/.*$ /news/story.php?id=$1
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do the directory checking in case the resource request didn't point to a real file, but should directly generate a 404 response, you can try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)$    /news/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Check if the path segment after /news/ corresponds to an existing directory
# and if so, don't perform the rewrite
RewriteRule %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/news/$1/ !-d
RewriteCond $1 !=tags [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/.*$ /news/story.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Tim. Your first solution worked perfectly, almost. The last problem we have is that we also have a rewrite for our tags, which goes to /news/tags/. So we need to make sure that if the URL has /news/tags/ don't rewrite to story.php either.

Comment: @scatteredbomb - No problem. For completeness, I went ahead and edited the answer with an additional check for that scenario, although putting the tag rewrite with the `L` flag before the story rewrite would also have been a possible solution, for the first option.

Comment: Thanks again. I wish I could give you more points for that :) I really appreciate your help.